# Resonance in benzene: creation of current

Tags: resonance

I am a student. I recently studied resonance in Benzene. I know that π electrons in Benzene are involved in resonance this means the electrons somewhat **move** in the process of resonance.

I have a question :

**If electrons are moving in Benzene there  should be a current?**

However I have not seen any such fact in the books i am currently studying. Please tell me if this thing happens in Benzene or not.

Comment: The current is within the molecule, the more interesting question, is shouldn't there be a magnetic field?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aromatic_ring_current

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment, but benzene has a ring current and that creates a magnetic field perpendicular to the current. Conversely, a magnetic field will create an induced current (Ampere's Law) in the ring (delocalized electrons from the pi bonds).